# How to format plaintext like a book/magazine with PHP?

Tags: php, formatting, plaintext, text-manipulation

I have:

```
This is a test string. Cool, huh?
```

I want:

```
This is a te-
st string. C-
ool, huh?
```

That is, each line is exactly 13 chars, ***according to the English rules for this***. That is, I'm not sure if "test" can be broken up like "te-st", or that "Cool" can be broken up to "C-ool", but that's the "style" I'm trying to achieve.

I've made about a thousand search queries. I find nothing whatsoever that does this.

wordwrap() is useless because it only works with entire "words" and leaves tons of blank space in the end of most lines.

This is so frustrating, because I can't continue my project until I've sorted this out. I assumed that there would be a library for this, but the only even remotely related I find is https://github.com/vanderlee/phpSyllable , but that doesn't seem to do this at all. The example makes no sense since it doesn't show any output and doesn't mention any line "width" anywhere.

Comment: I don't English has rules for hyphenation.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need this? I'm just curious if you're going about it the right way. Also have a look at the last parameter of wordwrap(cut).

Comment: Are you looking at fixed width, or using hyphenation rules?  You can’t just always break on the thirteenth character and be readable. Back in the olden days of typewriters, there were books showing where words could be split and the goal was to keep the right margin to within 5 characters or so.  Thirteen characters is not much to work with...

Comment: [You should be able to comment on your own post instead of responding in an answer.  My point was that your requirement, "each line is exactly 13 chars, according to the English rules for this" **is unobtainable**.  So which do you want, fixed width, or proper hyphenation?  You can't have both.  Your example needs to be a reasonable example of what you want.  `te-st` and `C-ool` imply that you are looking for fixed width, because these are in no way valid places to split a word.

Comment: FWIW, if you're using a browser to display your results, What you're looking for is accomplished with CSS.  For example `text-align: justify`.  Words aren't typically hyphenated much anymore...

Answer (score 1):

The libraries [Hyphenator](https://github.com/nikonyrh/hyphenator-php) or [Org_Heigl/Hyphenator](https://github.com/heiglandreas/Org_Heigl_Hyphenator) seem to be handling hyphenation properly. Based on one of those, you should be able to write your own `wordwrap()` able to use either spaces or hyphens as break points.

Note that English words have very specific hyphenation points, and you're absolutely not guaranteed to have each line exactly *n* characters long. Sometimes you'll fall a few characters short, if the next syllable just happens to be long - for example "thorough" hyphenates as *thor-ough*, while "through" does not hyphenate at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you should be able to work with, using some sort of hyphenation library. This code uses a fake 3-character hyphenation function. You can see it in action at https://www.tehplayground.com/eNtxiMTeXj16oPkT - it took me about 10 minutes to write this, so it was, in fact, trivial - contrary to what you wrote in the now deleted thread.

```php
<?php
$loremipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

function FAKE_hyphenate($word) { // use some real library's hyphenation function here
    return explode("-",wordwrap($word,3,"-",true));
}

function hyphenate_text ($text, $line_length) {
    $words = explode(" ",$text);
    $lines = [str_repeat("-",$line_length)];
    $line = "";
    while ($words) {
        $word = array_shift($words);
        if (strlen($line)+strlen($word)+1<=$line_length)
            $line .= (strlen($line)>0 ? " " : "") . $word;
        else {
            $syllables = FAKE_hyphenate($word);
            $syllables[0] = " ".$syllables[0];
            $syl_count=0;
            while ($syllables) {
                $syllable = array_shift($syllables);
                if (strlen($line)+strlen($syllable)<=$line_length-1) {
                    $line .= $syllable;
                    $syl_count++;
                } else {
                    array_unshift($syllables,$syllable);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($syl_count>0)
                $line .= "-";
            $syllables[0] = str_replace(" ","",$syllables[0]);
            array_unshift($words,implode("",$syllables));
            $lines[] = $line;
            $line = "";
        }
    }
    $lines[] = $line;
    return implode("\n",$lines);
}

echo hyphenate_text($loremipsum,25);
```